# How to rotate ImageView and have its size adjust automatically?

Tags: android, xml

Image 1 is without rotation,I want image 3 when I rotate `ImageView`, but something like image 2 is displaying. How can I have the `ImageView` change its dimensions automatically?
My guess is that after rotation, the width and height of the `ImageView` is preserved, and I do not want that
P.S. I don't want to change the orientation of the layout
here is the picture(Rectangle is the phone, person is the imageview)[image]

Here is my xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/page">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerInside" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/character" 
        android:rotation="90"
     />
    </FrameLayout>
<!-- I tried all scaleTypes, and set height/width to fill_parent, wrap_content,and match_parent nothing worked-->
```

any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/character"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:rotation="90"
 />
```

### Edit:

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

will set `scaleType="fitCenter"`, so I think you should try `scaleType` or `adjustBounds` ,no both.

```
 <ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/character"
    android:rotation="90"
 />
```

Comment: No luck sorry. I tried setting all the 'scaleTypes' possible before nothing worked. 'FitXY' distorts the image so that wouldn't work either

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true" ` will set  `set scaleType="fitCenter"` , your all try is useless !

Comment: yeah I tried without the 'adjustViewBounds' but that didn't work either. Tried 'centerInside' too

Answer (score 0):

Remove `adjustViewBounds` and use scaleType **fitCenter**. It should work. Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/character"
    android:rotation="90"
 />
```

Comment: No luck. Thanks tho!